# Extract Access Key from URL - YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, token

I have sent a request for an access token to the YouTube api, and once the user grants access to the application they are then redirected back to the page, and I can see in the URL that the access token is set with an expiration - my question is how do I extract that from the URL and store the access key in a variable?

The url looks like this:

`http://site.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=uploader/#access_token=token-here&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600`

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, to get the URL data from the Browser location bar:
If it contains for example the follwing url 
http://site.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wp2yt_uploader/#access_token=token-here&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

In chrome, FireFox and Internet Explorer.

var urlUsed = document.URL;

var p  = window.location.protocol;

var h  = window.location.host;

var pa = window.location.pathname;

var s  = window.location.search;

```
urlUsed == http://site.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wp2yt_uploader/#access_token=token-here&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

p == http:

h == site.com

pa == /wp-admin/admin.php

s == ?page=wp2yt_uploader/#access_token=token-here&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

Comment: How does one implement this? So p, h, pa, and s will be set to what parts of the url?

Comment: I tried to implement the variables and alert them, but none of the variables return anything past uploader/ (which was the pathname)

Comment: I used chrome and using alerts, i do get the string parts. Works also on FireFox. However not on Internet Explorer. Must be Browser depended.

Comment: How can I store the token? I have no been able to get it to authenticate, and the access token looks like it gets stored in a hidden field with in an iframe on my page. I am not able to target it with jQuery to store inside of a variable. How would I 'catch' the access token and store it for use?? It is no longer in the url

Comment: Maybe use a cookie ? To store use: document.cookie = c_value; To retrieve use: var c_value = document.cookie; (Does the iframe you mention not have any reference name, like id= or name= ?)

Comment: No not that I can see, It is just listed as `<iframe src="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=904907387177-qe517sq5dmmpebckjbmrhv4gvac9e2d1.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com&amp;immediate=true&amp;proxy=oauth2relay410978643&amp;redirect_uri=postmessage&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-site.com&amp;response_type=token&amp;state=735196902%7C0.858710575&amp;authuser=0" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; left: -100px;">`

Comment: I think you can extract it, if it has a container with an id or name, surrounding this iframe. You then extract the contents of that container first.

Comment: You are right, it is in the page. I can see a similar iframe as you on my page and below it is a document with a form, which contains an access_token. But a better way is to send the url yourself and then capture the response with the token, instead of extracting this. Since it is valid for a limited time.

Comment: I also get the alerts with correct content in Internet Explorer. (Did not see them the first time as i did quit to soon.) Also the complete URL is in: document.URL

Comment: Interesting. I will keep playing with it and see what I can come up with. Bit of a troubling problem as I need to store the access token in a variable so I can then use it to delete videos as needed